# How uninstall ocx control?

Tags: controls, uninstallation, ocx

We have signed OCX control for IE 6.0/7.0/8.0/9.0 browser. It was installed by *<object>* tag in *.html*.

How it can be completely removed from client computer?

**regsrv32** utility used for this purpouse. Is **regsrv32** perform another essential action or just call **DllUnregisterServer** from control?

I get code for **DllUnregisterServer** from Microsoft SDK Samples. Is that code enough to perform uninstall action?

How locate control on fs (control installed by browser) to get path to **regsrv32** utility?

How perform this action for 64-bit control?

Answer (score 3):

Locate the .dll that contains the control and run **regsvr32** with the **/u** switch:

```
regsvr32 /u control-filename.dll
```

Comment: Nice. I use this technique with development setup. But how automatically locate dll on client cumputer?

Comment: Try to find path to ocx in Windows registry. As I remember every ocx is linked with unique clsid.

Comment: @George Thanks. I found path to .ocx from default value for *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{B27A0357-C846-43E8-BF64-3ADBB977E468}\1.0\0\win32*. What is mistery 1.0 and 0 in this path?

Comment: *1.0* is two last arg of **IMPLEMENT_OLETYPELIB(CsignpluginCtrl, _tlid, _wVerMajor, _wVerMinor)** call. Seems */0/* is standard name in path...